# Changed appearance of Quantity expressions in v10.1.0

Tags: visualization, units, style

After installing Mathematica v10.1.0 (in Windows 8.1 x64), I noticed a change in appearance of `Quantity` expressions.

For example under Mathematica v10.1.0:
[image: Mathematica graphics]

while under Mathematica v10.0.2 (much better and "compact"):
[image: Mathematica graphics]

There is a way to restore the previous behavior, for example with some settings or style?

Sample data:

```
Dataset[{<|
   "RadiusRange" -> {Quantity[0., "Kilometers"], 
     Quantity[1221., "Kilometers"]}, 
      "Density" -> 
    Quantity[11818.135838172968, "Kilograms"/"Meters"^3], 
      "ElasticPWaveVelocity" -> 
    Quantity[10.347456160728301, "Kilometers"/"Seconds"], 
      "ElasticSWaveVelocity" -> 
    Quantity[3.02852859441218, "Kilometers"/"Seconds"], 
      "LaméFirstParameter" -> 
    Quantity[1049.5375275855597, "Gigapascals"], 
      "ShearModulus" -> Quantity[109.05337277524552, "Gigapascals"]|>, 
    <|"RadiusRange" -> {Quantity[1221., "Kilometers"], 
     Quantity[3480., "Kilometers"]}, 
      "Density" -> 
    Quantity[10900.09169347849, "Kilograms"/"Meters"^3], 
      "ElasticPWaveVelocity" -> 
    Quantity[9.086088441931578, "Kilometers"/"Seconds"], 
      "ElasticSWaveVelocity" -> Quantity[0., "Kilometers"/"Seconds"], 
      "LaméFirstParameter" -> 
    Quantity[911.4187086948931, "Gigapascals"], 
      "ShearModulus" -> Quantity[0., "Gigapascals"]|>, 
    <|"RadiusRange" -> {Quantity[3480., "Kilometers"], 
     Quantity[5701., "Kilometers"]}, 
      "Density" -> 
    Quantity[4738.516718235739, "Kilograms"/"Meters"^3], 
      "ElasticPWaveVelocity" -> 
    Quantity[12.258648710758479, "Kilometers"/"Seconds"], 
      "ElasticSWaveVelocity" -> 
    Quantity[6.704618882708015, "Kilometers"/"Seconds"], 
      "LaméFirstParameter" -> 
    Quantity[292.4455630105769, "Gigapascals"], 
      "ShearModulus" -> Quantity[215.19575310929594, "Gigapascals"]|>, 
    <|"RadiusRange" -> {Quantity[5701., "Kilometers"], 
     Quantity[6371., "Kilometers"]}, 
      "Density" -> 
    Quantity[3560.8022017268295, "Kilograms"/"Meters"^3], 
      "ElasticPWaveVelocity" -> 
    Quantity[8.789770753063875, "Kilometers"/"Seconds"], 
      "ElasticSWaveVelocity" -> 
    Quantity[4.786005931229413, "Kilometers"/"Seconds"], 
      "LaméFirstParameter" -> 
    Quantity[115.89195778000462, "Gigapascals"], 
      "ShearModulus" -> Quantity[84.2454280219151, "Gigapascals"]|>}]
```

Comment: I have in my imagination a model of professional development.  The newly hired developers need to get familiar with the system, so give them the task of making quantities look nice or entities etc.  (At Microsoft it seems to be why don't you completely redesign the menus the way *you* would like them.)

Comment: The display is controlled by a style called `"Quantity"`, which may be found in Core.nb or with `CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "Quantity"}]`.

Answer (score 2):

One could modify the stylesheet to change the style `"Quantity"`.  The existing style `"QuantityTF"` seems similar to the old style.  `Style` does not seem to work on `Quantity`, so I resorted to substituting it in the boxes.  (The variable `ds` is set to the OP's dataset.)

```
quantityForm[expr_] := 
 CellPrint@
  Cell[BoxData@ToBoxes[expr, StandardForm] /. 
    TemplateBox[q_, "Quantity", opts___] :> 
     TemplateBox[q, "QuantityTF", opts], "Output"]

ds // quantityForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The differences in the styles can be inspected with

```
CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "Quantity"}]
CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "QuantityTF"}]
```

The principal difference is in the option `TemplateBoxOptionsDisplayFunction`, in which the style `"Quantity"` wraps the output in a `PanelBox`.

Comment: Nice work. Still hope WRI revert to previous, better, aspect by default